# Nao Robot Cross Compilation Issue

Tags: cross-compiling, nao-robot

I have the following problem:
I have successfully cross-compiled my ALModule and everything works fine, e.g. works on the Nao and I can access it with a ALProxy. This works only as long as I have only methods which are binded to the Module via BIND_METHOD and don't call other methods (which are not binded, since there shouldn't be public). Now I tried to find a solution for this and I am kinda stuck with that.

To sum it up: I can cross-compile the ALModule successfully to a libname.so file and put it on the NAO, but as soon as my binded methods use some other methods which were created by me the Module won't load and won't show up in the Module Register.

Does anybody knows a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Never heard about that kind of problem.
Did you read errors when lauching naoqi manually on your nao giving you clue about loading problems ?

eg: your method are on another cpp and you forget to link it...

If it's more complex, you should send a source package to the forum...

Comment: I already got an answer to it on the official Aldebaran Robotics Forum. Thanks nevertheless. It was indeed a failure when launching the naoqi.